# Runtime Error 3061 Too Few Parameters Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to Access. I have made a form to put the data in the table.
I have one one combo box and one text box in the userform.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub add_Click()
'Add Data to the GroupHeads Table
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert into GroupHeads(AccountHeads, GroupHeads)" & "  Values(" & Me.cboaccounthead & ", '" & Me.txtgrouphead & "')"

End Sub
```

Please review and advise why its giving runtime error.

Regards.
Salman

Comment: This often happens because you've got a column name wrong. Confirm that the columns in the table match the names of the columns that you're inserting into. Also can you confirm that `AccountHeads` column is a numeric data type? Finally watch for `Me.cboaccounthead` containing quote characters as this will break the `insert` statement - you might need to wrap `Me.cboaccounthead` inside a `Replace` function.

Comment: Columns name are correct... AccountHeads and GroupHeads are defined as ShortText. How i will replace the combobox text using replace function..

Answer (score 0):

If both columns in the table are text then *both* values need to be enclosed in single quotes, so you need:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert into GroupHeads(AccountHeads, GroupHeads) " & _
    "Values('" & Replace(Me.cboaccounthead, "'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & Replace(Me.txtgrouphead, "'", "''") & "')"
```